# random floating points generator in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have generated a figure of  4 x 4 area in matlab. Now I need to place more than 200 points(Actually moving device) on this area randomly but distributed evenly all over 4 x 4 area. I am using the following line to randomly generated the x and y co-ordinate to select the place for each of the different points.

```
a =200;
x_base = randi([1 5], 1, a);
b = rand([10 8], 1);
 y_base = randi([3 7],1, a);
```

With the above code I can get only integer co-ordinates for x and y. Hence am not able to distribute the points evenly all over the area. This is because I am using randi function which generates integer only. I would like to know is there any way of generating floating point numbers randomly so that I can distribute the points more evenly?

I am looking for random floating point numbers between 1 to 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select `n` random points in the 4x4 area from (0, 0) to (4, 4)?

```
unifinv(rand(n, 2), 0, 4)
```

Answer (score 5):

`rand`

Generates a number between 0 and 1.

`rand(m,n)` generates an m-by-n array of such numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
   minVal = 1;
   maxVal = 20;
   r = rand(1) * (maxVal - minVal) + minVal
```